# Android - using showFindDialog with Fragments - No Searchbar

Tags: java, android, search, android-fragments, webview

I know that showFindDialog is depreciated, but it serves a function that I need in my webview.  To that end, I am using this code in my fragment to display a spinner selection in a webview:

```
        if (wv != null) {
            Log.d("Log", "Search Method");
            wv.showFindDialog(null, true);
        }
```

The point of this code should be pretty self explanitory, but it offers a search bar in the actionbar along with next, previous, and a "checkmark" button to dismiss the search.

My problem is that after switching to then from the fragment, in the navigation drawer, the search option does not display the search text entry or any of the buttons, but it does show the keyboard.

My fragment menu is using these details:

In onCreate I have:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

I call the onCreateOptionsMenu and inflate a separate menu than the one that is being used by the MainActivity, I clear the menu options with:

```
menu.clear();
```

Finally, my onOptionsItemSelected uses a switch/case type to run the method:

```
search();
```

and finally the search method:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void search() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        if (wv != null) {
            Log.d("Log", "Search Method");
            wv.showFindDialog(null, true);
        }
    } else {
        searchOldMethod();
    }
}
```

*Note - I am not concerned about the searchOldMethod(); that is shown above.

I am linking a photo of what occurs below.  This happened after I switched from the shown fragment to another fragment, and back again.  I hit search and only the keyboard populated. (hosted on imgur):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3LIj.jpg

Does anyone know why this happens?

The Fragment:

```
package com.example.fragmenttest.app;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
ProgressBar pd = null;
public static final String PREFS_NAME2 = "SearchFile";
Spinner spLoadFrom;
WebView wv;

private LinearLayout container;
private Button nextButton, closeButton;
private EditText findBox;

private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter;

String name[] = { "Stuff" };
String displayName[] = {
        "stuff" };

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    //create a option menu for the current Fragment displayed, add setHasOptionsMenu(true); to the Fragment onCreate() method
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    container.removeAllViews();

    //Use View "v" containing the layout and container - use v.findViewById in others
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.atcsectionweb2, container, false);
    wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    pd = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.pBar);
    spLoadFrom = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.Spinner02);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, displayName);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spLoadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    SpinnerListener spListener = new SpinnerListener();

    spLoadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(spListener);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return v;
}

public class SpinnerListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    public SpinnerListener() {
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                               final int position, long arg2) {

        WebView wv = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);

        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress < 100
                        && pd.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                    pd.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
                pd.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    pd.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + name[position]);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

//inflate the corresponding option menu by override the onCreateOptionsMenu() method
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    Log.d("Log", "Inflating Menu");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.blank, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

//handling menu selections override the onOptionsItemSelected()
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mySearch:
            Log.d("Log", "Implementing Search Method");
            search();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_settings:
            //do something
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void search() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        if (wv != null) {
            Log.d("Log", "Search Method");
            wv.showFindDialog(null, true);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Search is only supported on Android version 4.0 and higher.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```